# Detect if WebSocket connection is terminated on server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, em-websocket

I want to handle differently different cases of WebSocket connection termination. I should send email if it's terminated on client side by logout or browser closing. And I should do nothing if it's terminated on server side (for example after the server restart).

Is there a way to detect in what way connection is terminated?

I use Rails 4.2 and em-websocket gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There **shouldn't** (by design) be a way to determine the reason for the websocket connection closing, *but*...

... It is possible to program **some** closure events into your application (both client-side and server-side), allowing you to guess other reasons.

Also, websocket disconnections can happen due to loss of connectivity (network cable unplugged, lost Wi-Fi/cellular reception, system crash etc'), a situation which is usually detected after a longer while - a connection could seem open (known as a [`half-open` state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_half-open) ) while being closed.

Most servers will detect the situation in up to a minute or so (that's long). Read more about it [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html).

For server shutdown, you can leverage the [`Karnel.trap` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-trap). If you were using [Plezi](http://www.plezi.io) you'd probably be able to leverage an `on_shutdown` in your controller (I'm biased, as I'm the author)... from your comment I've learned that em-websockets doesn't have a similar callback, and I'm sorry about that.

To use the `trap` method, you catch the exit signal and perform any necessary actions before forwarding it. i.e. (it's not very DRY, you can improve on the concept):

```
old_int_trap = trap('INT') do
   puts "do something"
   old_int_trap.respond_to?(:call) && old_int_trap.call
end
old_term_trap = trap('TERM') do
   puts "do something"
   old_term_trap.respond_to?(:call) && old_term_trap.call
end
```

Or, if the server closes the connection for it's own reasons (authentication, misbehavior, etc'), you can easily set up a flag telling the `on_close` (`onclose`?) callback to do nothing.

Client logout is easy - send a message before logging the user out.

Browser shutdown can be the default (no other reason for closure).

Disconnections are hard, but you could keep a variable storing the time of last websocket message, allowing you to assume an issue if no messages were received for more than 30 seconds since the last message.

...

**BUT:**

Personally, I would consider using a `completed` websocket message before actions such as emails etc'. I think "whitelisting" events is a better approach.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation! I've tried to use Kernel.at_exit method, but it works in the very end, after invocation of the onclose callback. em-websocket doesn't have on_shutdown callback.

Comment: @SergeiStruk - I'm sorry the `at_exit` didn't work... Another option is to catch the signal before the exit process starts, do something and than forward it. I edited my answer, please have a look.